# exporting SAS file to CSV

Tags: csv, sas, export

i am having a problem exporting a SAS file to a CSV file. When exporting to CSV assigned variable "values" are being exported instead of the raw numbers. For example dichotomous variables with raw values of "0" or "1" in the SAS file are being exported using their assigned "values" of "yes" or "no" instead of the raw values of 0 or 1 to the exported CSV file.

Is the code to assure that the raw values(e.g 0 or 1) are exported?

Thanks

Comment: Is it many variables? You can strip any formats easily...for all variables but that may not be what you want.

Comment: Please show what code you used to create the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You have formats applied to your data then.

You can remove the format ahead of time or apply it as needed to generate the data you want. ODS CSV is a good way to do this as you can easily control the formats within a proc and test it easily.

```
ods csv file='/folders/myfolders/demo.csv';
   proc print data=sashelp.class noobs;
   format age 8.2; *formats variable as numeric with 2 decimal places;
   run;
ods csv close;
```